# Nested calls using Retrofit in android

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retroofit beta1 2.0.

I am calling hacker news api for topstories.json to get the item ids. On the onResponse() of the first call, I am iterating through the item ids and make second call to "item/{itemid}.json".

In the onResponse() of the second call, I am setting the local list variable with Item class populated by Response.body(). I can see the results in log.

But I am not able to display in the RecyclerView UI. Please help.

```
private final List<Item> mItemList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<Integer> itemIdsList = new ArrayList<>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvEmptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.item_recycle);
    handler = new Handler();

    // load the data over network
    loadData();

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);

    mDataAdapter = new DataAdapter(mItemList, mRecyclerView);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mDataAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
  }

private void loadData() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    final HackerNewsAPI hackerNewsAPI = retrofit.create(HackerNewsAPI.class);

    Call<int[]> callItemIds = hackerNewsAPI.loadItems();

    callItemIds.enqueue(new Callback<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<int[]> response) {
            int[] itemIds = response.body();
            for (int i : itemIds) itemIdsList.add(new Integer(i));

            for (int itemId : itemIdsList) {

                Call<Item> callItems = hackerNewsAPI.loadItem(itemId + ".json");
                callItems.enqueue(new Callback<Item>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response<Item> response) {
                        Item item = response.body();
                        mItemList.add(item);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        System.out.println("inside failure");
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the callback happens async, you're going to want to reference your recyclerview adapter in the onResponse body. Add the items to the list of items in the adapter and then notify that the data set has either changed or that you've added items.

Comment: I tried setting mDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in both onResponse() methods, but the UI didn't get updated.

Comment: You need to add the new items to the list in the adapter as well before calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I have added this code in the sucess of the second call. and still not able to see the records.                                                           mDataAdapter.setmItemList(mItemList);
mDataAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mItemList.size());
mDataAdapter.setLoaded();
mDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: are you sure you're getting data back in the second call?

Comment: yes. I am getting the data and I can print it out in the System.out log

Comment: Could be an issue with your adapter then maybe? Are you able to see anything from your recycler before the calls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89469/discussion-between-j-krishna-and-chris-thoma).